# Notify.js with AngularJS: pass $scope content to notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, notify

Is there any way to pass Angular variables into a Notify.js function?
I've tried making my function in scope of Angular with my $.notify() inside the function but it doesn't run.  If i move the function outside of the scope of the app as a plain JS function it runs just fine but then I can't use Angular stored data in it.

I have:

```
function showAchievement () {
  $.notify({
    title: '{{angularData}}',
    message: '{{moreData}}.'
  }, {
    type: 'achievement',
    placement: {
      align: "left"
    },
    animate:{
      enter:'animated fadeInLeft',
      exit:'animated fadeOutRight'
    },
    delay: 5000
  });
}
```

and my CSS:

```
.alert-achievement {
  background: url("../img/purple-bg.png") no-repeat;
  border: 4px solid purple;
  color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
} 

.alert-achievement > [data-notify="title"] {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.alert-achievement > [data-notify="message"] {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

It works just fine outside of Angular.  It's even being triggered inside Angular. I just need to pass the title and message based on the content of an Angular $scope.title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parameters on the function:

```
function showAchievement (title, message) {
  $.notify({
    title: title,
    message: message + '.'
  }, {
    type: 'achievement',
    placement: {
      align: "left"
    },
    animate:{
      enter:'animated fadeInLeft',
      exit:'animated fadeOutRight'
    },
    delay: 5000
  });
}
```

Then invoke the function with the scope variables as arguments:

```
showAchievement($scope.angularData, $scope.moreData);
```

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: Thanks!  I had actually tried that but I had forgotten to add $scope before angularData.  The IDE recognized it but it didn't work.  oops.